# How to make NoData transparent?

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

I have been using python to turn a netcdf into a geotiff. 
Once I have the geotiff, I am using gdalwarp to transfer it into the right projection. Then use gdal_translate to get the tif into a vrt file.

I then use the vrt with gdal2tiles.

The problem is, when I get my tiles, I end up with my NoData showing up as the bottom or top of my color ramp. In the image shown, I set NoData to be 0. 
[image]

I have tried adding a color ramp two different ways, one with a color-relief using gdaldem. When I do that, I get a

`Error : band 1 has no color table`

from gdal_translate.
I have also used python to set the ColorTable.

**All I want is for my NoData to be transparent. Any idea on how to do that?**

EDIT: How I create my array, I then use osgeo to make the tif.

`noData = array == fill_val
norm_array = array.copy()
norm_array[noData] = 0`

I have tried many different options once I have the tif,

`gdalwarp -overwrite -ts 1736 932 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -srcnodata 0 -dstnodata 0 -dstalpha original.tif warpped.tif`

I have also tried using the `-a_nodata` for gdal_translate and the `-a` option for gdal2tiler as well. None of that seems to be working.

Comment: Have you told the gdal utilities what your NoData value is? Please edit your question to show the commands you used.

Comment: How are you going from NetCDF to Geotif? I use a `numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray` when processing NetCDF data in Python: ideally the underlying data already has actual no data values; if not you can use a `numpy.ma.masked_where` to cast values to null. You might need to cast 0 to null in this step, but I don't know what Geotif does with null/transparent data.

Comment: gdal2tiles.py displays noData cells as transparent for me... it looks like in your image the cells displayed as cream-colored have values of 0. In my original raster I had noData cells defined as "0"... so I used gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 input.tif output.tif to specify the "0" tiles as noData... After using gdalwarp to reproject to 3857 and then running gdal2tiles.py the noData tiles displayed as transparent for me.